# Does Lefty the dwarf exist in Shrek?

Tags: shrek

Last year, I got Shrek 2 Top Trump Cards from a charity shop and one the 7 Dwarfs one, it said:

There used to be eight dwarfs, but Lefty’s following his dreams in the minor league.

Does this “Lefty” even exist in Shrek?

Update: Here’s the Top Trump Card:
[image]

Comment: Snow White only had 7; apparently, they were upset with Lefty enough to keep him out of that also!

Answer (score 3):

Although it's hard to prove a negative (and accepting that there may be mention of him in something *truly obscure*), Lefty the Dwarf appears to exist solely within *that particular* Top Trumps cards game.

No mention of him can be found in the films, short films, nor any of the tie-in novels/novelisations/young reader books, factbooks, film interviews, musicals, ride stands (at Universal Studios), DVD extras from any of the films or their tie-in short films, nor any of the video games.